# How can I free some disk space without deleting my apps?

Tags: storage, internal-storage

I dont have that many apps. But I had to delete old ones to get new ones because my phone keeps saying I have low storage.

**How can I free some disk space without deleting my apps?**

Comment: What device and Android version do you have?

Comment: i have a mytouch slide and i think its 3G

Answer (score 2):

The only way that I am aware of is if you don't want to remove apps from your device, you could remove the app data associated with them. Certain apps take up quite a large amount of space, Google Maps is an example of this if you use it regularly.

To delete the app data go to settings > Applications > Manage Applications and click on a app name and then click on the All Tab. You may want to click on Menu > Sort by size so it will show you what apps are using the most space from the top of the screen.

To clear the app data click on the app name and then click on the clear data button.

Do this for a couple of apps and the low storage space warning should eventually disappear, you may have to go through quite a few apps though. This is what I have to do on quite a regular basis unfortunately.

Another tip, the browser tends to store a lot of data, but if you click on clear data for the browser you will lose everything including bookmarks. Instead from the browser press menu > more > settings  and then clear things like history and cookies etc.

Hope this helps

Comment: Clearing Data removes all application settings.  Those usually don't take as much space as Cache.  Try deleting app Cache first instead, by tapping the "Clear Cache" button on that same screen.

Answer (score 1):

If your phone is rooted, you can [CacheMate](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aac.cachemate.demo&feature=search_result) to automatically clear your applications' caches for you on set intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Some apps that I know of like Instagram, Facebook, Maps tends to accumulate a lot of internal space to store their cache, it is not unusual to find cache by Facebook and Instagram reaching up to hundreds of MBs mainly due to video cache and images in my phone, you might want to check them first.

Also if you have apps with very large apk files try to move them to sdcard. In some rare cases I found that dalvik cache also contains some dexes of previously uninstalled apps....you can try to clear dalvik cache too in recovery or manually if you have a rooted phone.

Check some other apps if any that use streaming or internet connectivity especially social media apps, they tend to store a lot of cache.

If your phone is rooted you can try to remove bloatware that came pre-installed in your phone