# Why my phone is always out of space recently, but I didn't install any new software

Tags: storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I free some disk space without deleting my apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14630/how-can-i-free-some-disk-space-without-deleting-my-apps)

I've installed such software as Shazam, Baidu Map, QQ, HiMarket, MeiTuan, UC Mobile, etc. At first everything is fine, but nowadays the phone always says "Low on space". What should I do?

Comment: There are also several other similar questions with advice on how to find out what's taking up space and how to clear out some of that space. Check the [tag:internal-storage] tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be the applications occupying /data/ space as they are in use, mainly due to runtime files, cache, database, etc.

In order to verify this, you can execute the following:

```
adb shell
su -c "du /data" | sort -n
```

It should have a result like:

```
...

3792    /data/data/com.UCMobile
28399   /data/app
35647   /data/data
49374   /data/dalvik-cache
114865  /data/
```

And then you can check the directories from large to small, to see what's taking so much space.

Answer (score 2):

It could also be a good idea to clear the apps cache. You can do so manually, going to *settings -> applications*, opening each app, and hit the "clear cache" button -- or use a helper app as e.g.

- [CacheCleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.lsartory.cachecleaner)/[CacheCleaner NG](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.lsartory.cachecleaner.ng)
- [Android System Cleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tools.androidsystemcleaner)
- [App Cache Cleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.cache)
- [Cache Clear](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.menue.cacheclear)

All these are available for free on the ma... play store, do *not* require root access, and do the cleaning automated with one tap only. There are many more available, if you want to check out...