# What else is occupying my android phone's internal space

Tags: storage, hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTC Desire low on internal storage, I'm clueless — Any help?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/htc-desire-low-on-internal-storage-im-clueless-any-help)
>   [Something is secretly eating up my tablet memory and I need help finding it](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27127/something-is-secretly-eating-up-my-tablet-memory-and-i-need-help-finding-it)

I have a HTC Desire phone with android system, which has 148M internal storage and 250M system storage. My internal storage usually works well, but as times goes on, it become less and less, and finally I have to uninstall some software in order to install a new one, and update several app at one time is not even an option as the storage limitation. But:
I only have 17 apps installed, each on average is less than 3M, and I even installed most of them in SD card, I really don't see any reason that my apps will eat up all internal storage, but, what else could it be?

Thanks.

Comment: Cached Internet files?

Comment: Please take a look at the items listed in the "Linked" section, which probably already solve your problem: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/htc-desire-low-on-internal-storage-im-clueless-any-help / http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25707/why-my-phone-is-always-out-of-space-recently-but-i-didnt-install-any-new-softw / http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27127/something-is-secretly-eating-up-my-tablet-memory-and-i-need-help-finding-it